# how to close inner modal if it is in another component in angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have a "customers" component (parent component), and it is related with "customer-page" component (child component).

In parent component, there is a modal, calling child component. In child component there are two more models which work as if all of those three are in the same component.

But when i close the modal of child component, it also closes the parent component's modal.

**How can i fix that?**

Customers Component HTML (Parent component HTML):

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="mymodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Customer's Page</button>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">customer info</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <app-customer-page [customer]="currentCustomer"></app-customer-page>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Customer-Page HTML (Child Component HTML):

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-inner" title="Edit"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm" title="Delete"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="myModal-inner" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Customer Info</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <app-add-order [order]="currentOrder"></app-add-order>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Attention</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>This operation cannot be undone. Are you sure?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Customer Page Component HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
data-toggle="modal"
```

Your modals are binded to same variable named modal. Use different name for each modal in data-toggle.